# converting/analyzing .csv to xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am currently attempting to write a script that converts a .csv file to a .xlsx file, then do some data analysis on the new file. I am currently running into an error when trying to copy the new file i make.

here is the error:

```
  File "C:/Users/mmunoz/Desktop/Excel Analysis/danielaScript1.0.py", line 40, in <module>
    workbookCopy = xlutils.copy(workbook)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**Here is my original code**

```
import os, csv
import glob
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import xlrd
import statistics as st
import xlutils.copy

position = []
load = []
positionMM = []
force = []

csvfile = input('Please input filename: ')

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    workbook = Workbook(csvfile + '.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, col in enumerate(row):
                columb_letter = get_column_letter((c+1))
                s = col    
                try:
                    s= float(s)
                except ValueError:
                   pass
                worksheet.write(r, c, s)


#%% 
 #workbook1 = xlrd.open_workbook(workbook)  
 workbookCopy = xlutils.copy(workbook)
 sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)              
 numRows = sheet.nrows
 numCols = sheet.ncols
 for row in range(2, numRows):
     position.append(sheet.cell_value(row,2)) #appends values in column to       position array
     load.append(sheet.cell_value(row,3))#appends values in column to load array
```

Comment: The code above is incomplete and may also be improperly indented. I think you need to focus on smaller pieces of your task, and make sure each of them is working before trying to put it all together. For example, how about just saving each CSV as an .xlsx file, without any additional processing. Right now, the code above doesn't even do that.

Comment: I also think you will find that you can't really use xlutils at all. That module is for serving as a bridge between xlrd and xlwt, and you cannot use xlwt to create .xlsx files.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your input @John Y. As of right now My script is successfully creating .xlsx files from the original csv files. But if I cannot use xlwt to create xlsx files, I will need to start my project over. Do you have any advice on how to approach my task:

that is, to take a csv file with friction data, convert the data to different units, then output the new set of data

Comment: There are two viable approaches. (1) Read the CSV data in, then do whatever processing you need right then and there, and finally write the *finished* data out to .xlsx. (2) Convert the CSV data to .xlsx as you are doing now, but then use OpenPyXL instead of xlutils. OpenPyXL is vaguely like a combination of xlrd and XlsxWriter. Personally, I like xlrd and XlsxWriter, and I don't like OpenPyXL; but OpenPyXL is the simplest way to both read and write to a .xlsx file in the same program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xlutils.copy is a module.

Try this:

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
```

then

```
workbookCopy = copy(workbook)
```

More info:  http://xlutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/copy.html

Comment: I am receiving the a new error now:

AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'datemode'

Comment: That's a different question - if I answered this one you should probably mark it as the answer.

The docs for Workbook don't indicate that datemode is an attribute so why would you think it is?

http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html